# Would a more general version of "why was [X] light novel not animated" be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I recently voted to close [Why wasn't the Death Note light novel animated?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48884/why-wasnt-the-death-note-light-novel-animated) for being opinion-based, but it got me thinking: would a general version of this question (e.g. Why are light novels not usually animated?) be on-topic? It seems like it would have a non-opinion-based answer. But if it is on-topic, why is the more specific version not?

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: The question has been posted at [Why do light novels tend not to be animated directly?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48892/why-do-light-novels-tend-not-to-be-animated-directly)

---

If you can create a more general (or "canonical") Q&A for this topic, then go for it!

At least we have precedences for this:

1. [Why do anime have manga adaptations? Why don't authors just focus on one medium at a time?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34119/why-do-anime-have-manga-adaptations-why-dont-authors-just-focus-on-one-medium)
2. [Why don't more video games get full anime adaptations?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22559/why-dont-more-video-games-get-full-anime-adaptations)

The reason why (I believe) the *Death Note*/specific version one is off-topic is because we have to know *that certain reason* why it's not yet adapted. Unless it's mentioned somewhere else, then it's speculation at best. (note: I've done some quick research before closing it, but nothing came up, thus I feel it's better to close it before it gets speculative answers)

Providing a canonical Q&A at least can point the asker *safely* for "the possible reasons". (Whether to link it as "related", or close as a dupe, it's another question...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really about the question (and others like it), but our lack of expertise and inside knowledge. Questions such as "Why was X not B" expose an inherent flaw with our community -- the fact that we cannot are able to draw from industry specific knowledge even if it was made public in some magazine, tweet, or TV interview, simply because we are secondary consumer of the media.

I'm sure the question mentioned by the OP has been brought up by other fans in Japan closer to the source. Information from those involved in the production rarely ever trickles down from overseas unless it's a hugely popular and well-known franchise, simply due to costs. We can't provide non-opinionated sources unless we can either draw on anecdotal analogies or try to piece thing together from bits and pieces gleamed from Japanese media sources (magazine, videos, tweets, etc).

Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange by association has been overly rigid with criteria in an attempt to make things more readable. Questions that are answerable with simple yes or no are discouraged, you may say because it's a question and answer site. There are times that a question just does not have a concrete answer, but the question itself is still valuable and so are any answers. I believe that questions like the one mentioned by the OP are like these type of questions and we should look at approaching them in another direction in order to be more welcoming to new contributor.

Just like in programming, things like best practices, or conventional approaches, possibly what existing tools/frameworks/libraries might solve a problem. Yes, those are going to be opinionated answers. That doesn't make them not valuable. It also doesn't detract from more concrete questions and answers. I do not believe we have to budget space and needs to prioritize one set of questions/answers over another. We are a recreation site. We should at least explain why these questions are hard to answer. It frustrates new contributors when well simply close things and tell them it's too broad. Try as we they may to accommodate, but our lack of expertise on certain areas make it difficult to explain why we can't help them.

I am finding that the "downvote and move" methodology on has the be one of the worst internet philosophies to develop, when applied to literally anything other than spam or duplicated posts it poisons online communities. We should we try think or converse with new contributors and explain what the problem may be on both sides instead of hiding behind canned messages. We need new blood in order to grow, but in order to attract new blood we need to be more welcoming and empathetic. We're a niche space on a niche topic, we can afford to do some experimenting to see where we can go.